# Smoothing a single rectangular pulse in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, functions

Hello I am interested in smoothing out the sharp edges of a single rectangular wave centered at the origin.

I am looking for a smooth function that looks almost exactly the same as the square wave except it is differentiable everywhere.

I looked at Fourier Series but this creates a periodic function which I do not want. 
I want to create a rectangular wave of finite height and zero everywhere else.

Ultimately, I want to plug this approximating function into NDSolve in attempt to get rid of "spiky" effects present in the solution of the wave equation.

Thank You!

Edit::

This is the square pulse in question: 
[image]

Comment: how about the sum of two `Tanh`? I think the proper parametrization (how steep you make them) needs some information about your problem...

Comment: Hello, I edited my post. This is the square wave I would like to approximate using a smooth function. Ultimately, such approximating function will be used as a initial condition to solve the linearly damped wave equation.

Comment: Somehow, a graph doesn't seem that precise.  Where are the discontinuities? `x = -8.5` and `x = 8.3`?

Comment: Hello @MichaelE2, I don't think I phrase my question correctly, I was talking about undifferentiability at the points -8.5 and +8.5. I was trying to smooth this out in order to differentiate it everywhere along the Interpolating Function (I wanted to see if these sharp edges were contributing to fuzzyiness of my interpolating function (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60772/increasing-maxpoints-in-ndsolve-results-in-memory-issue)).  I am currently trying to integrate ub[0.1][x] to find the area of the inital rectangular wave pulse from -infinity to +infinity.

Comment: @MicahelE2 But ub[epsilon_] isn't defined everywhere along the x axis. It looks like the interpolating function doesn't define y value of zero everywhere except for inside of the rectangular wave. I tried adding points such as {-200,0},  and {200,0} to extend the domain of my function, but doing this operation doesn't produce a plot. Is there a way to do this? Thank You!

Comment: Problem is solved. Other points are not necessary I plugged in u[-10] and it gives me a value of zero. Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  See my update for another way to do it.

Comment: Closely related: [A: NDSolve for PDE with discontinuous initial/terminal condition](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17311/245)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `NDSolve`, an `InterpolatingFunction` might be sufficient.  Here are smooth versions of `UnitStep` and `UnitBox`, with a smoothing "radius" of `epsilon`.

```
us[epsilon_] := 
  Interpolation[{{{-epsilon}, 0, 0}, {{epsilon}, 1, 0}}, 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {If[# < -epsilon, 0, 1] &, "WarningMessage" -> False}];
ub[epsilon_] := 
 Interpolation[   
  {{{-1/2 - epsilon}, 0, 0}, {{-1/2 + epsilon}, 1, 0},
   {{1/2 - epsilon}, 1, 0}, {{1/2 + epsilon}, 0, 0}}, 
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {0 &, "WarningMessage" -> False}]
```

Example

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] + ub[0.1][(x - 6)/6.5] y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 15}];
Plot[y[x] /. First[sol], {x, 0, 15}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Response to updated question**

You could construct an explicit interpolation for your particular use case instead of using the generic functions `us` and `ub`.  For example, for the updated question, one could replace the `± 1/2` by `± 8.5` in `ub`, or by arbitrary cutoffs `a`, `b`, if a general function is needed, as follows.

```
smoothbox[a_, b_, epsilon_] /; a < b && epsilon > 0 := Interpolation[{
    {{a - epsilon}, 0, 0}, {{a + epsilon}, 1, 0},
    {{b - epsilon}, 1, 0}, {{b + epsilon}, 0, 0}},
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {0 &, "WarningMessage" -> False}]

GraphicsRow@{
  Plot[smoothbox[-8.5, 8.5, 2.5][x], {x, -15, 15}],
  Plot[smoothbox[-8.5, 8.5, 2.5][x], {x, 5, 12}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]